# Repeat background image untill a specific point before end of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image that repeats. Is there any way for the image to stop repeating 100px before the div ends no matter how tall the div is?

Unfortunately the div height will vary from page to page so I can't set a specific height or use a bigger image instead of repeating.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to stop the repeat at a certain point. What you can do though is push everything below the div down 100px with margin

```
div
{
    background-image:url("http://blog.lyris.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Google-Logo.jpg");
    height:1000px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7RM2x/